# Keras custom metric

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

How can I create a custom metric that on a categorical problem accepts as correct predictions not only when the predicted category and the true one are the same, but also when the predicted category is a neighbour category of the true one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
def one_off(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.abs(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1) -  K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)) < 2, K.floatx())
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is valid if you consider that "only one class" should be output.

```
def neighbourMetric(yTrue,yPred):

    #these make this function not differntiable, but since you asked for "metric" it's ok
    trueIndices = K.argmax(yTrue)
    predIndices = K.argmax(yPred)

    minAccepted = trueIndices - 1
    maxAccepted = trueIndices + 1


    satisfiesMin = K.cast(K.greater_equal(predIndices,minAccepted),K.floatx())
    satisfiesMax = K.cast(K.less_equal(predIndices,maxAccepted),K.floatx())

    satisfiesBoth = satisfiesMin * satisfiesMax

    return K.mean(satisfiesBoth)
```